# Analytic function in the closed unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> If $f: \overline{\Delta}=\overline{\Delta}(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous nonconstant that is analytic in $\Delta = \Delta(0,1)$ and satisfies $|f(z)|=1$ for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=1$, prove that 
>   $$f(z) = c \prod_{k=1}^r \left( \dfrac{z-a_k}{1-\overline{a}_kz} \right)^{m_k}$$
>   for every $z \in \overline{\Delta}$, onde $a_1,a_2,...,a_r$ are distinct point in $\Delta$, $m_1,m_2,\ldots, m_r$ positive intergers and $c \in \mathbb{C}$ is such that $|c|=1$.

Here is what i got:

Looking to the formula that we have to get, i see that $a_i$'s are the zeros of the function, so I have to find then.
Since the modulos of the function is one is the boundary of the unit disc, then we know that $f$ has at least one zero in $\Delta$, lets say $a_1$ with multiplicity $m_1$.

$$f(z) = (z-a_1)^{m_1}g(z)$$

where g is analytic in $\overline{\Delta}$ and $g(a_1) \neq 0$.

What I don't know how to prove:

> $f$ have a finite number of zeros in $\Delta$.

Suppose I know that. Lets say the zeros are $a_1,a_2, \ldots, a_r$ with respective multiplicity $m_1,\ldots,m_r$. Then

$$f(z) = (z-a_1)^{m_1}(z-a_2)^{m_2} \ldots (z-a_r)^{m_r}h(z)$$

where $h$ is analytic in $\overline{\Delta}$ and $h(a_k)\neq 0$ for $k=1,\ldots,r$.

Two things I think I have to use now
\begin{eqnarray}
|f(z)|= |(z-a_1)|^{m_1}|(z-a_2)|^{m_2} \ldots |(z-a_r)|^{m_r}|h(z)|=1
\end{eqnarray}

and $\left| \dfrac{z-a_k}{1-\overline{a}_kz} \right| = 1$ if and only if $|z|=1$.

> How I know that $h$ looks like $h(z) = \dfrac{c}{(1-\overline{a}_1z)\cdots (1-\overline{a}_rz)}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$f$ has a zero of order $n$ at $z=0$, look at $g(z) = z^{-n}f(z)$. It is analytic on $|z| < 1$ and continuous on $|z| \le 1$ and $|g(z)|=1$ for $|z|=1$. Then $$G(z) = \begin{cases}g(z) \text{ for } |z| \le 1 \\ 1/\overline{g(1/\overline{z})}\text{ for } |z| > 1 \end{cases} $$ is meromorphic on $|z| \ne 1$ and continuous on $\mathbb{C}$. By the Schwarz reflection principle, it is meromorphic everywhere. Also $\lim_{z \to \infty} G(z) = 1/\overline{g(0)}$ so $G$ is analytic for $|z| > R$ large enough.

$G$ has (with multiplicity) a finite number $k$ of poles on $1 < |z| \le R$, so that $$H(z)=G(z) \prod_{m=1}^k (1-a_m z)$$
is entire and bounded by a polynomial of degree $k$. By the Liouville theorem $H$ is a polynomial of degree $k$, and
$$G(z) = C \frac{\prod_{m=1}^{k} (z-b_m)}{\prod_{m=1}^k (1-a_mz)}$$
Finally, since $h_c(z)=\frac{1-cz}{z-c}$ is bounded as $z \to \infty$
$$J(z) = G(z) \prod_{m=1}^{k} h_{a_m}(z)$$
is entire and bounded so it is constant. And hence
$$G(z) = \frac{1}{J(1)}\prod_{m=1}^{k} \frac{z-\overline{a_m}}{1-z a_m}$$
Where $|J(1)|=1$ as desired.

Comment: Why is $f$ zero at $z=0$? Your proof is more sophisticated and use results that a don't know yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof sketch for finite zeroes:

Holo + not constant, so use discrete mapping to obtain that set of zeros is discrete. Since zero set is discrete, it can be at most countable. Suppose for contradiction that it is not finite. Then we have an enumeration of zeroes, ie a sequence, this sequence is bounded. Use Bolzano Weirstrauss to obtain an accumulation point, then use identity theorem to conclude that f is identically zero, a contradiction.